# Feeding multiple sample rates to the same buffer source : ffmpeg filters

Tags: c, ffmpeg

I have a remote source of PCM audio samples which keeps changing the sample rate. It sometimes supplies 16Khz and the later 48Khz depending upon the bandwidth. I would like to convert them to FLTP through a filter, before feeding to an audio decoder. When I do that I get the error "Changing audio frame properties on the fly is not supported. [Invalid argument]".

Can someone please suggest a way this can be done?

Is it possible to create a filter graph with multiple buffer sources but only one sink?

Comment: Unfortunately, at this time, an audio buffer source expects the input properties to remain constant. When using the ffmpeg cli, the filtergraph will be reinited when input props change.

Comment: @Gyan I used av_buffersrc_parameters_set() to change the sample rate on the fly. Got "Not yet implemented in FFmpeg, patches welcome". So you are right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used swr_convert_frame() keeping an array of SwrContext * for different input sample rates.